# Android studio ndk build hangs with clang running?

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android Studio NDK module with about 200 small C files I'm trying to build as a native library.   When I do a build either from within Android Studio or from the command line with gradlew, the build process hangs part way thru compiling one of the files.  Which file it hangs on is random from build to build.  When the build hangs the only recourse is to kill the clang process(es) and try again.  On rare occasions it will actually complete.

One guess I have is that there is some windows issue with multiple simultaneous compiles for the module.  Is there a way to force make to use -j1 to test this?

Are there other reasons the build would hang?

Environment - Windows 10, Android Studio 2.3.3, Gradle 3.4.1

Comment: _"Is there a way to force make to use -j1 to test this?"_  How about `externalNativeBuild { ndkBuild { arguments "-j1" } }`?  (or, if you're invoking `ndk-build.cmd` directly in an `Exec` task, just add `'-j1'` to your `args`/`commandLine`).

Comment: adding the ndkBuild{} option gives an error - Could not find method arguments() for arguments[-j1] on object com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.NdkBuildOptions.  Looks like the only allowed option is path.

Comment: Where did you put this exactly? I meant the `externalNativeBuild` block inside `defaultConfig`.

Comment: I had it in the android block that had externalNativeBuild.  Moving it to the defaultConfig/externalNativeBuild block it no longer generates an error but appears to have no effect.  I still see a dozen clang instances while building and the build still frequently hangs.